# is there a way for the server to save clients' addresses and send updates (for all or some clients) to an open html page?

Tags: javascript, php, html, sockets, push

here is what I want to do:

on a website: www.mySite.com

I want ppl to log on and be able to see other ppl who are currently viewing that webpage.
then I want them to be able to enter text on the webpage and it sends a message to the server
the server then sends this message to all the ppl viewing the page.

then I want the option to select a user from the list of users currently viewing the webpage.
and send that user alone a message (private messaging) but not all the others.

can I do this with html and php? I do NOT want to have a browser refreshing constantly to reload data.
I have looked into websocket technology and so far the only solutions I found is to open a socket connection, wait for a response from server and close the connection on timeout...
then reopen a new one and continously open and close sockets until updates are received by server.

is there a way for the client (browser) to listen for updates without polling a server?

**-->>>is there a way for the server to save client addresses and send updates to an open html page (push data) to all those clients, only specific ones, or whatever the case is??<<--**

html seems to work fine polling servers but then close connection right away.
Is there a way to keep a socket open indefinately, and not constantly reopen them to simulate server-browser push technology?

I am coding with a simple webserver using html, php and javascript. I am not paying for a virtual machine where I can construct services in my language of choosing.

I prefere not to use a 3rd party to achieve this.

I would like for this to be working on all browsers.

is this possible?

Comment: the problem is that php doesn't do long-running stuff very well. you can leave a connection open and push more data out later, a technique known as COMET, but it has a lot of complications and spotty browser support. ajax2 long-poll (via http1.1) is the best flavor if you go that route.

Comment: oh, and if there were a widely-compatible way of doing exactly what you're asking, within the limits you describe, this question would have half a dozen answers by now.

Comment: yea i looked into comet and its not interesting... long polling either seems to have too many problems....

Comment: i feel like the problem is from the browser itself. the application is built to send requests to a ready server and to receive responses in short amount of time. it is not made to acces the user's computer and listen, indefinately to a certain port, for any message passed specifically to your device. in essence this would be what id like the app to do. but browsers just dont have this feature.... so long-polling, and other tricks are used to mimic this.

Comment: the internet was invented for spooks and scientist to fetch and publish static research files. you can look into EventSource; it's like write-only sockets as far as your server is concerned. WebSockets proper would be perfect as well, but i don't think php would be very good for websockets.

Comment: Ive tried server sent events. it reconnects every 3 seconds

Comment: SSE certainly should not be reconnecting like that, it can stay open a long time. you may want to try again because if it connects at all, you're pretty close. may i ask why you don't want to use one of the many services that makes this sort of task easy?